# Preparation of Copper (II) Sulfate Pentahydrate Solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ph, concentration, adsorption

how would you make a solution of Copper (II) Sulfate Pentahydrate to achieve 150, 200, 250 and 300 mgL−1 concentration of copper? I do not have the anhydrous version of the solute. Also, when I dissolve it in water, does it become acidic? If so, how would I maintain it at pH 7 without messing up the concentration? I am going to use the solution for adsorption studies if anyone is asking. thanks for the replies!

Comment: (1) Mass of anhydrous $\to$ moles of anhydrous $\to$ moles of pentahydrate $\to$ mass of pentahydrate. (2) Yes it will become acidic, and _you don't want to_ maintain it at pH=7.

Comment: I dont get what you mean by on number one, can you please elaborate? And about the pH level, is it highly acidic or just beteween 4-6 pH?

Comment: (1) You want to make a certain amount of solution with certain concentration; can you find out how many grams of _anhydrous_ CuSO4 (if it were available, that is) would you need for that? (2) Slightly acidic.